# What program can I use to convert RAW images from my Sony camera to jpeg?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

I have a Sony camera and need to know what app to use to convert my RAW images into jpegss. My camera is a Cybershot RX100 and my version of Ubuntu is 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Depending on what the digital camera does for raw images, there are plug-ins for GIMP that can be installed like `gimp-ufraw` and `gimp-dcraw`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick is another good tool for the image conversion. To install this package run below command:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out whether [RawTherapee](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/rawtherapee) or [DarkTable](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/darktable) could deal with them...

(Chances are at least one of them could...)

If yes, then it would bring the added benefit of being able to *tune your images before* converting them into lossy jpegs (or anything else).